# Set active class on Bootstrap Nav-pills

Tags: ember.js

I'm using `.nav-pills` to create a ui element to select the route in my app like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    {{#each item in model}}
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
                {{item.name}}<b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                {{#each child in item.children}}
                    <li>{{#link-to 'child' item child}}{{child.name}}{{/link-to}}</li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

It works great, but I can't figure out awhile to get the `li.dropdown` to have `.active`. I've tried using `link-to` helper and setting it to the parent route, but that doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after posting this, it dawned on me that I had used the `item.index` route for the `link-to` that I was using for `li.dropdown`. I changed it to just `item` and it works perfectly now.

To summarize:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    {{#each item in model}}
        {{#link-to 'item' item tagName='li' classNames="dropdown"}}
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
                {{item.name}}<b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                {{#each child in item.children}}
                    <li>{{#link-to 'child' item child}}{{child.name}}{{/link-to}}</li>
                {{/each}}
            </ul>
        {{#link-to}}
    {{/each}}
</ul>
```